# Android Notification: String Next to App Name, Using setCustomContentView

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to specify a string between the app title and the time stamp of a notification, for example, the "dpark@gmail.com" string in this notification: 
https://developer.android.com/images/ui/notifications/wear_2x.png

The catch is that I also want to use a custom notification/setCustomContentView.

**Current code:**

```
RemoteViews mNotificationLayout = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.small_notification_layout);

Notification mCustomNotification;
mCustomNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setCustomContentView(mNotificationLayout)
    .build();


NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(001, mCustomNotification);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your current code, but what you see is done with this code:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("Me")
.setConversationTitle("dpark@gmail.com")
```

Comment: My apologies.  Had not considered different notification styles. I have updated my question. And indeed, your code does not work with my current code.